# VBA: pasting from clipboard unreliable

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, powerpoint, paste

I am trying to copy a range of cells from Excel and paste it onto a slide of a PowerPoint presentation (both version 2016) with the original formatting.

I tried

```
Allg.Copy
mySlide2.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3).Name = "AllgShape"
```

and it works most of the time, but not always. 
The following runtime error happens from time to time:

> '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes.PasteSpecial: Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or conains data which may not be pasted here

because (I think) the clipboard is not populated in time. Therefore I tried this to just repeat the copying and pasting process if an error happens:

```
ALLGCOPY:
  Allg.Copy
  On Error GoTo ALLGCOPY:
  mySlide2.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
  myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3).Name = "AllgShape"
```

It seems that the error handler does not exactly what I think it does because sometimes it just pastes the same shape 2 times when running this code.

Then I tried

```
Allg.Copy
PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3).Name = "AllgShape"
```

but then sometimes there's an issue with the assigning of the name for the shape, because it does not paste fast enough.

so I added a timer after the pasting

```
Public Sub Warten(ByVal MilliSekunden As Double)
   Dim i    As Double
   Dim ENDE As Double

   ENDE = Timer + (MilliSekunden / 1000)

   Do While i < ENDE
      DoEvents
      i = Timer
   Loop
End Sub
```

But this is unreliable because sometimes 100ms are sufficient, but sometimes even 2000ms aren't sufficient and I want the macro to run on most (also older) machines.

Preferably I want to work with the error handler and not with the timer as it is unreliable and depending on CPU usage.

Can someone tell me why the code with the error handler does not work and is sometimes pasting the same shape 2 times?

**EDIT:**
apparently my understanding of how the error handler works was insufficient. It is possible to solve my problem with the according use of the error handler.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of adding time, have you tried using `DoEvents`?

Comment: With timing issues I normally use Application.Ontime; try to seperate your 3 commands in seperate subs and call each of them with Application.Ontime Now, "name of sub1" etc.

Comment: Clipboard events run more slowly than VBA does. So you have to delay code. DoEvents is one possibility, but I prefer using Sleep: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00466_Put_your_macro_to_Sleep.htm

Comment: @JohnKorchok this sleep times does basically the same thing as my timer. The problem with that is - as I described above - that it is not reliable and sometimes a time of 1000ms is sufficient, sometimes not. This is not an acceptable solution for my specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions that need answers are "How do I wait until the clipboard has data?" and "How do I know when pasting is complete".  For the first question, based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51285401/5162073) amongst others, you could do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PasteSomeData()
   Dim i As Integer

   ClearClipboard
   Allg.Copy

   Do While isClipboardEmpty() And i < 5
      i = i + 1
      Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
   Loop

   If Not isClipboardEmpty() Then
      mySlide2.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
      myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3).Name = "AllgShape"
   End If
End Sub
```

Since we are looping until the clipboard has data, we need to provide a mechanism to prevent an infinite loop.  I chose to try 5 times with a 1-second pause between each try.  Adjust these values as needed.  In a module, I had the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CountClipboardFormats Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Function ClearClipboard()
   OpenClipboard 0&

   EmptyClipboard

   CloseClipboard
End Function

Public Function isClipboardEmpty() As Boolean
    OpenClipboard 0&

    isClipboardEmpty = (CountClipboardFormats() = 0)

    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

Now, in regards to the second question, I don't have a good answer.  You may be forced to pause for some amount of time like you did in your question and has been suggested in the comments.

Comment: I wonder if there is any alternative method of moving texts/images/objects from here to there without using clipboard.  The clipboard is a specific memory allocation, that I know of.  And It is accessible from many other processes of your computer simultaneously. A clipboard failure is inevitable in a subroutine where 150 or more iteration of image/object clipboard copy-paste actions take place, from my observation.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of error-trapping is the right path. Here's how to repeat the wait time until an error is no longer generated:

```
    Allg.Copy
TryPaste:
    On Error GoTo TooFast
    mySlide2.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
    On Error GoTo 0
    myPresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(3).Name = "AllgShape"
    Exit Sub

TooFast:
  Warten
  Resume TryPaste
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. I had to add an additional afterTryPaste jumpmark so it won't be trapped in an endless loop, but it seems to work. I will test it a few more times

Comment: @ClemensAmbros It doesn't seem like this would fix `there's an issue with the assigning of the name for the shape, because it does not paste fast enough`.  But you could probably apply the same technique.

Comment: @BrianMStafford apparently my problem with the timer had to to with insufficient understanding of how the error handler works. It is now possible for me to create a trapper where a timer is called if the paste.special does create an error and then retry it - this does solve my problem. Nevertheless I appreciate your (more elegant) answer.

Comment: Impressive.  Is there any chance of this code causing infinite loop?

Comment: It could only cause an infinite loop if some condition had made it impossible to paste. The only circumstance I can think at the moment is if a previous copy or cut operation failed. But you should be trapping those operations as well.