# Error when pasting in excel from pdf with SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, sendkeys

I am trying to copy a whole pdf document into excel using the following code. The code works perfectly except for the paste part, when it gives me the following error:

> "run time error 1004 pastespecial method of range class failed".

But it is really weird because after that, it will let me paste it manually into the excel, so the data is in the clipboard.

I have tried many different paste formulas but none of them are working. I do not know how to fix the error.

Thank you for your help. Find below the code that I am using

```
Dim varRetVal As Variant, PathToPDF As String, strCommand As String


PathToPDF = "C:\Users\takyar\Desktop\test1.pdf"

PathToPDF = pdf_file_FR

strCommand = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " & PathToPDF

' Use Shell Function to open Adobe Acrobat Reader

varRetVal = Shell(strCommand, 1)
' wait
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

'First select all data of PDF file, next copy to clipboard

SendKeys "^a" 'select all data
SendKeys "^c" ' copy data
'Wait

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
'Close Acrobat Reader or PDF file

SendKeys "%{F4}"

' Wait
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

' Paste to added worksheet (PDFText)

SendKeys "^c"

'Range("A1").Select

Sheets.Add.Name = "FRpdfinfo"

Worksheets("FRpdfinfo").Select

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: You do not have the `PasteSpecial` property from the PDF that you are copying since this belongs to Excel and not to Adobe, you can only `Paste` normal. Give [this](https://www.exceldemy.com/vba-paste-from-clipboard-to-excel/) a read if needed.

Comment: @sgdva Thank you for your help, but I have tried using `Paste` and I will get the same error. Also I have tried the three method stated in the webpage but I will get an error. Except for the `Sendkeys v`, but nothing happened, it will not paste it despite selecting the range previously to pasting it.

Comment: Then you need to do the sub stated as "Paste_from_Clipboard" from that webpage, I'm guessing you are getting an error there because you need to [wait until the clipboard has contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544795/vba-pasting-from-clipboard-unreliable)